# Ng-repeat ,firebase and lots of data models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/1nvdzv24/

i have my data form firebase like this

```
$scope.gotData={
  "date": {
    "date": "11/23/24"
  },
  "menuList": {
    "item1": {
      "val1": "a1",
      "val2": "a2",
      "val3": "a3"
    },
    "item2": {
      "val1": "b1",
      "val2": "b2",
      "val3": "b3"
    },
    "item3": {
      "val1": "c1",
      "val2": "c2",
      "val3": "c3"
    }
  }
}
```

i show the data on the screen where the user can edit like this:

```
<ul class="formContainer">
 <li ng-repeat="(name,rates) in gotData.menuList" my-repeat-directive>

    <label for="{{name}}">{{name}}</label>
     <span ng-repeat="(rateType,val) in rates">
       <input type="text" id="{{rateType}}" value="{{val}}">
     </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

i have a button at the end

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="updateData()">update Data</button>
```

what i want to do is that when the user clicks the update button the data gets updated in the corresponding node on firebase. i am only wanting an update not a set or remove in this case.

How do i do that?

Comment: and what have you tried? you can iterate values, check what has changed and update the changed node.

Comment: i  have tried to watch the values using the "on()" method of firebase..the real problem is to assign the correct data element from the page to the firebase elem

Comment: Please make sure that the fiddle reflects the approach you tried. The link now takes me to a piece of HTML+JavaScript that seems to have little to do with what you have in your question. Also ensure that both the question and the fiddle include the actual code you tried. Finally: make sure you study the Firebase documentation *and* search StackOverflow for similar questions. The topic of binding Firebase objects to Angular has been covered quite often already.